# How to use Range to calculate multiple ranges of cells?

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I made 127 ranges of cells, because they are located separately,
the code is like this

```
Dim c1, c2, c3 As Range
Set c1 = Range("W2: AO128")
Set c2 = Range("AR2: BJ128")
Set c3 = Range("BM2: CE128")
SolverOK SetCell:="$U$282", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=Range("c1, c2, c3")
```

it replies error message "method range of object _Global failed" in the solverok function line

does anyone know how to solve it?
thanks

Comment: do you want to change `c1` & `c2` & `c3` ranges or `c1:c3` cells?

Comment: You need to create a union of all those ranges. By creating them as separate variables you've made your life a little more difficult than if you'd used an array...

Comment: Should also review this link - http://www.solver.com/standard-excel-solver-dealing-problem-size-limits#Limits on Decision Variables  You have too many changing cells in your model.

Comment: @KazJaw  c1,c2, c3 are all different ranges of cells on the sheets, and have been defined already

Comment: @Tim Williams i need to use several ranges to define the dv because they are located separately and has values i need in constraints. And I have downloaded a tool from sover.com, it could handle 5000 decision variables instead.  I met the # of dv is out of range error msg before, its different from this one

Comment: @JamesChen - I posted that link for *after* you fixed your current problem (not knowing you had the solver upgrade)  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array would make this easier...

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng(1 To 127) As Range, x As Long, rngAll As Range

Set rng(1) = Range("W2: AO128")
Set rng(2) = Range("AR2: BJ128")
'....etc


For x = 1 To 127
    If Not rng(x) Is Nothing Then
        Set rngAll = Application.Union(rng(x), rngAll)
    Else
        Set rngAll = rng(x)
    End If
Next x
Debug.Print rngAll.Address()
'...
'SolverOK SetCell:="$U$282", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:=rngAll

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me :

```
    SolverOK SetCell:="$U$282", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:="W2:AO128" & ";" & "AR2:BJ128" & ";" & "BM2:CE128"
```